# Local storage not being populated with my form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to create a web app that tracks poker buyins. I have a form that users can enter their name and buy in and I'm attempting to save it to `localStorage` and then render the data, but my `localStorage` is only showing as an empty array after I click submit.

This is my `useEffect` code:

```js
const [numPlayers, setNumPlayers] = useState(2);
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  //loading player data on mount
  const storedData = localStorage.getItem("playerData");
  if (storedData) {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
    setPlayerData(JSON.parse(storedData));
    setNumPlayers(parsedData.length);
  }
}, [setPlayerData, setNumPlayers]);
```

My `handlesubmit`:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const newPlayers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= numPlayers; i++) {
    const name = formData.get(`player${i}-name`);
    const buyIn = parseInt(formData.get(`player${i}-buy-in`));
    if (name && buyIn) {
      newPlayers.push({ name, buyIn });
    }
  }
  setPlayers(newPlayers);
  localStorage.setItem("playerData", JSON.stringify(newPlayers));
  setPlayerData(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("players")));
  console.log(newPlayers);
};
```

Any help is appreciated I have always had trouble with local storage!

Answer (score 0):

Before we begin, there are a couple issues with you code that you need to figure out first.

### 1. Dependencies

Your `useEffect` dependencies are going to cause many issues with your code as you build more complex UIs, or if you introduce hydration. You never put the React State Setters in the dependency array unless they are wrapped with `useCallback`.

You probably meant to use the state variables (not the setters)

❌ DON'T DO THIS

```js
useEffect(() => {
    ...
}, [setPlayerData, setNumPlayers]);
```

✅ DO THIS

```js
useEffect(() => {
    ...
}, [playerData, numPlayers]);
```

### 2. React State vs DOM

Whenever possible, you want to avoid DOM functions. There are some cases that you'll require DOM functions, such as adding event listeners, interacting with non-ReactJS widgets, etc... but forms are not one of these cases.

You want to use state variables to track form data rather than using `e.target.[whatever here]`. This will help prevent discrepancies between the DOM and ReactJS's VDOM.

### 3. JavaScript Nullishness

> Note: This might solve your problem

You aren't using explicit nullish checking:

```js
if (name && buyIn) newPlayers.push({ name, buyIn });
```

You would think that the above condition will add `{name, buyIn}` as long as `name` and `buyIn` are not `null` or `undefined`. **That assumption would be wrong.**

Since `name` is a string, it would be equivalent to `false` if `name` is equal to `''` (empty string), `null`, or `undefined`.

Since `buyIn` is a number type, it would be equivalent to `false` if `buyIn` is `0`, `NaN`, `null`, or `undefined`. When calling `parseInt`, the function can return either `0` or `NaN`... so this may be causing your issue where the element is never added to the array.

---

### Overall...

There is no way to know for sure (with the limited code given) what is causing your code to load an empty array.

You should try the following steps:

1. Go to Chrome console window
2. Go to "Application"
3. Go to Storage -> Local Storage
4. See the stored value

If the stored value contains a populated array, then the issue is within the `useEffect` hook. Otherwise, if the array is being stored as an empty array, then #3 might be the most probable solution.